# Сколько времени нужно, чтоб выучить JavaScript на хорошем уровне?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста,  меня интересует вопрос засколько можно выучить javascript при усердной практики примерно 4-5 часа в день?

Comment: Выучить любой язык можно за день, а научиться программировать и за всю жизнь не каждому дано.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf ну за день, это вы загнули, язык _c_ не выучишь за день) А вообще, вы правы, научится писать правильный код на одном даже языке можно и за годы не научится.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич я lua освоил за день. Он от js не так уж сильно отличается. Если вы хорошо знаете хотя бы один любой язык, то все остальные буду даваться гораздо легче.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf Это если у вас за спиной есть опыт в других языках программирования, а если вы не знакомы с программированием вообще, тогда я не соглашусь

Comment: За день не реально выучить даже HTML,  я пробовал

Comment: Уже полгода верстаю на HTML и CSS все равно многое не понимаю

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич да, согласен, поправил свой коммент. Опыт в других языках играет ключевую роль.

Comment: Я с 0 выучил базу html и css за 4 дня, не имея знакомства с программированием, но только потому что css/html это не языки программирования вовсе.

Comment: Ну а хотя-бы его понимать,  для простенький скриптов,  или чтоб разбираться в jquery

Comment: html теги и css свойства я тоже выучил примерно за неделю,  но чтоб сносно верстать макеты,  да так чтоб ничего не поплыло, и полгода мало

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4-5 часов в день для изучения синтаксиса, думаю, что максимум неделя. А вот применять новые навыки на практике..., на это уйдут месяцы. 
Программирование всегда хорошо идет под задачу, будет задача будете искать решение, читая, видя и набирая код придут и опыт и практика :)

Comment: Советую так-же поставить перед собой задачу, написать простое приложение, работу с rest api возможно написать примитивную логику на сайт для меню, сделать свой слайдер - это все поможет вам быстрее выучить и освоить данный язык

Comment: А я бы посоветовал сначала досконально освоить ООП и только потом изучать язык, если вы действительно желаете научиться писать код на хорошем уровне.